# regex for capture groups

Tags: r, regex

I'm still learning Regex. I am trying to capture the groups in `()` below for `strcapture`. Any help with the regex expression to define the two capture groups in the texts below appreciated!

**Example 1**

```
1. 4301 TMA_Scan1_Core[1,1,A]_[10844,40623]_component_data.tif - resolution #1
```

to capture:

```
1. (4301) TMA_Scan1_Core[1,(1,A)]_[10844,40623]_component_data.tif - resolution #1
```

**Example 2**

```
3. TMA A_Scan1_Core[1,1,A]_[4600,36783]_component_data.tif - resolution #1
```

to capture:

```
3. (TMA A)_Scan1_Core[1,(1,A)]_[4600,36783]_component_data.tif - resolution #1
```

May require two different patterns to distinguish example 1 from example 2?

```
dput(test)
structure(list(Image = c("1. 4301 TMA_Scan1_Core[1,1,A]_[10844,40623]_component_data.tif - resolution #1", 
"2. 4302 TMA_Scan1_Core[1,6,B]_[12511,47333]_component_data.tif - resolution #1", 
"3. TMA A_Scan1_Core[1,1,A]_[4600,36783]_component_data.tif - resolution #1", 
"4. TMA B_Scan1_Core[1,9,E]_[12695,54120]_component_data.tif - resolution #1"
)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Image = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

substituting "pattern" below to capture groups 1 and 2 into "File" and "ID"

```
out <- strcapture("pattern", test$Image, list("File" = "", "ID" = ""))
```

to get:

```
out<- as.data.frame("File"= c("4301","4302", "TMA A", "TMA B"), "ID" = c("1A","6B","1A","9E"))
```

Comment: Please state the precise rules for making these replacements.  Also, please include any code you have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following :

```
strcapture('\\d+\\.\\s(\\w+)(\\s[A-Z]).*\\[\\d+,(\\d+,[A-Z])', test$Image, 
           list("File1" = "", "File2" = "", "ID" = "")) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(File2 = replace(File2, grepl('^\\d+$', File1), NA), 
                ID = sub(',', '', ID)) %>%
  tidyr::unite(File, File1, File2, na.rm = TRUE, sep = '')

#   File ID
#1  4301 1A
#2  4302 6B
#3 TMA A 1A
#4 TMA B 9E
```

The logic is as follows :

We capture the data in 3 columns.

`File1` - first word after a number and a dot (`\\d+\\.\\s`)

`File2` - Space along with one uppercase letter (`\\s[A-Z]`)

`ID` - Number and uppercase letter within `[]`.

We replace `File2` value with `NA` if they have only numbers in them. Remove comma from `ID` column and combine `File1` and `File2` columns removing `NA` values.